# Weyl Spinors in Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: field-theory, inertial-frames, spinors, dirac-matrices

I am self studying Quantum Field Theory from Peskin and Schroeder and am working on part (a) of exercise 3.4. I noticed that equation 3.29 gives a transformation formula for Dirac Gamma Matrices:
$$\Lambda_{(0, 1/2)}^{-1} \gamma^\mu \Lambda_{(1/2, 0)} = \Lambda_{\nu}^\mu \gamma^\mu,$$ where $\Lambda_{(0,1/2)}$ is for right handed spinors and the $\Lambda_{(1/2, 0)}$ is for left handed spinors. Now can I replace the gamma matrix in this transformation law and say $$\Lambda_{(0, 1/2)}^{-1} \bar{\sigma}^\mu \Lambda_{(1/2, 0)} = \Lambda_{\nu}^\mu \bar{\sigma^\nu}~?$$ If so why?

Note: here $\bar{\sigma} = (1, -\sigma_x, -\sigma_y, - \sigma_z)$

Comment: Hint: Try writing out the transformation law in the Weyl basis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Weyl_(chiral)_basis

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thank you. Now just to be sure when I try to prove/disprove the relation for $\bar{\sigma}^\mu$, do I use the usual representation of the Pauli Matrices? Is there a chiral representation for the Pauli matrices?

Comment: You shouldn't need to plug in any values for the Pauli matrices. How they transform follows from $\Lambda_{(0, 1/2)}$ acting on one type of index and $\Lambda_{(1/2, 0)}$ acting on the other.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thank you !!!